# Angular js SharePoint 2013 data binding is not working

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint-2013, office365

I am trying to implement the search of list items from SharePoint using app model where I am using angular js as client side framework.

I am not getting any issue in the page load but at the same time not able to see the respective binded data in the html.

here is the entire code

```
<%-- The following 4 lines are ASP.NET directives needed when using SharePoint components --%>
    <%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
    MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Language="C#" %>
        <%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
        %>
            <%@ Register TagPrefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
            %>
                <%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
                %>
                    <%-- The markup and script in the following Content element will be placed in the <head>of the page --%>
                        <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
                            <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
                            <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.0/angular.min.js"></script>
                            <meta charset="utf-8">
                            <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
                            <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/2.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
                            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
                            <style type='text/css'></style>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                if(typeof jQuery == 'undefined')
                                    {
                                        alert ('typeof jQuery == undefined');
                                    }
                            </script>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                var sortingOrder = 'name';
                            </script>
                            <script type='text/javascript'>
                                //<![CDATA[ 

                                        function ctrlRead($scope, $filter) {
                                            // init
                                            $scope.sortingOrder = sortingOrder;
                                            $scope.reverse = false;
                                            $scope.filteredItems = [];
                                            $scope.groupedItems = [];
                                            $scope.itemsPerPage = 5;
                                            $scope.pagedItems = [];
                                            $scope.currentPage = 0;
                                            $scope.items = [
                                                {"id":"1","name":"name 1","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 1","field4":"field4 1","field5 ":"field5 1"}, 
                                                {"id":"2","name":"name 2","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 2","field4":"field4 2","field5 ":"field5 2"}, 
                                                {"id":"3","name":"name 3","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 3","field4":"field4 3","field5 ":"field5 3"}, 
                                                {"id":"4","name":"name 4","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 4","field4":"field4 4","field5 ":"field5 4"}, 
                                                {"id":"5","name":"name 5","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 5","field4":"field4 5","field5 ":"field5 5"}, 
                                                {"id":"6","name":"name 6","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 6","field4":"field4 6","field5 ":"field5 6"}, 
                                                {"id":"7","name":"name 7","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 7","field4":"field4 7","field5 ":"field5 7"}, 
                                                {"id":"8","name":"name 8","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 8","field4":"field4 8","field5 ":"field5 8"}, 
                                                {"id":"9","name":"name 9","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 9","field4":"field4 9","field5 ":"field5 9"}, 
                                                {"id":"10","name":"name 10","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 10","field4":"field4 10","field5 ":"field5 10"}, 
                                                {"id":"11","name":"name 11","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 11","field4":"field4 11","field5 ":"field5 11"}, 
                                                {"id":"12","name":"name 12","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 12","field4":"field4 12","field5 ":"field5 12"}, 
                                                {"id":"13","name":"name 13","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 13","field4":"field4 13","field5 ":"field5 13"}, 
                                                {"id":"14","name":"name 14","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 14","field4":"field4 14","field5 ":"field5 14"}, 
                                                {"id":"15","name":"name 15","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 15","field4":"field4 15","field5 ":"field5 15"}, 
                                                {"id":"16","name":"name 16","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 16","field4":"field4 16","field5 ":"field5 16"}, 
                                                {"id":"17","name":"name 17","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 17","field4":"field4 17","field5 ":"field5 17"}, 
                                                {"id":"18","name":"name 18","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 18","field4":"field4 18","field5 ":"field5 18"}, 
                                                {"id":"19","name":"name 19","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 19","field4":"field4 19","field5 ":"field5 19"}, 
                                                {"id":"20","name":"name 20","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 20","field4":"field4 20","field5 ":"field5 20"}
                                            ];

                                            var searchMatch = function (haystack, needle) {
                                                if (!needle) {
                                                    return true;
                                                }
                                                return haystack.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
                                            };

                                            // init the filtered items
                                            $scope.search = function () {
                                                $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.items, function (item) {
                                                    for(var attr in item) {
                                                        if (searchMatch(item[attr], $scope.query))
                                                            return true;
                                                    }
                                                    return false;
                                                });
                                                // take care of the sorting order
                                                if ($scope.sortingOrder !== '') {
                                                    $scope.filteredItems = $filter('orderBy')($scope.filteredItems, $scope.sortingOrder, $scope.reverse);
                                                }
                                                $scope.currentPage = 0;
                                                // now group by pages
                                                $scope.groupToPages();
                                            };

                                            // calculate page in place
                                            $scope.groupToPages = function () {
                                                $scope.pagedItems = [];

                                                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.filteredItems.length; i++) {
                                                    if (i % $scope.itemsPerPage === 0) {
                                                        $scope.pagedItems[Math.floor(i / $scope.itemsPerPage)] = [ $scope.filteredItems[i] ];
                                                    } else {
                                                        $scope.pagedItems[Math.floor(i / $scope.itemsPerPage)].push($scope.filteredItems[i]);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            };

                                            $scope.range = function (start, end) {
                                                var ret = [];
                                                if (!end) {
                                                    end = start;
                                                    start = 0;
                                                }
                                                for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
                                                    ret.push(i);
                                                }
                                                return ret;
                                            };

                                            $scope.prevPage = function () {
                                                if ($scope.currentPage > 0) {
                                                    $scope.currentPage--;
                                                }
                                            };

                                            $scope.nextPage = function () {
                                                if ($scope.currentPage < $scope.pagedItems.length - 1) {
                                                    $scope.currentPage++;
                                                }
                                            };

                                            $scope.setPage = function () {
                                                $scope.currentPage = this.n;
                                            };

                                            // functions have been describe process the data for display
                                            $scope.search();

                                            // change sorting order
                                            $scope.sort_by = function(newSortingOrder) {
                                                if ($scope.sortingOrder == newSortingOrder)
                                                    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;

                                                $scope.sortingOrder = newSortingOrder;

                                                // icon setup
                                                $('th i').each(function(){
                                                    // icon reset
                                                    $(this).removeClass().addClass('icon-sort');
                                                });
                                                if ($scope.reverse)
                                                    $('th.'+new_sorting_order+' i').removeClass().addClass('icon-chevron-up');
                                                else
                                                    $('th.'+new_sorting_order+' i').removeClass().addClass('icon-chevron-down');
                                            };
                                             $scope.$apply(); 
                                        };
                                        ctrlRead.$inject = ['$scope', '$filter'];

                                        //]]>
                            </script>
                        </asp:Content>
                        <%-- The markup and script in the following Content element will be placed in the <body>of the page --%>
                            <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
                                <div ng-controller="ctrlRead">
                                    <div class="input-append">
                                        <input type="text" ng-model="query" ng-change="search()" class="input-large search-query" placeholder="Search">
                                        <span class="add-on">
                                            <i class="icon-search"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th class="id">Id&nbsp;
                                                    <a ng-click="sort_by('id')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a>
                                                </th>
                                                <th class="name">Name&nbsp;
                                                    <a ng-click="sort_by('name')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a>
                                                </th>
                                                <th class="description">Description&nbsp;
                                                    <a ng-click="sort_by('description')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a>
                                                </th>
                                                <th class="field3">Field 3&nbsp;
                                                    <a ng-click="sort_by('field3')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a>
                                                </th>
                                                <th class="field4">Field 4&nbsp;
                                                    <a ng-click="sort_by('field4')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a>
                                                </th>
                                                <th class="field5">Field 5&nbsp;
                                                    <a ng-click="sort_by('field5')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a>
                                                </th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tfoot>
                                            <td colspan="6">
                                                <div class="pagination pull-right">
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == 0}">
                                                            <a href ng-click="prevPage()">« Prev</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li ng-repeat="n in range(pagedItems.length)" ng-class="{active: n == currentPage}" ng-click="setPage()">
                                                            <a href ng-bind="n + 1">1</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == pagedItems.length - 1}">
                                                            <a href ng-click="nextPage()">Next »</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tfoot>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr ng-repeat="item in pagedItems[currentPage] | orderBy:sortingOrder:reverse">
                                                <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                                                <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                                                <td>{{item.description}}</td>
                                                <td>{{item.field3}}</td>
                                                <td>{{item.field4}}</td>
                                                <td>{{item.field5}}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

I drilled it down and followed the basic approach of binding the module and controller.

the changed code is below

```
<%-- The following 4 lines are ASP.NET directives needed when using SharePoint components --%>
    <%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
    MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Language="C#" %>
        <%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
        %>
            <%@ Register TagPrefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
            %>
                <%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
                %>
                    <%-- The markup and script in the following Content element will be placed in the <head>of the page --%>
                        <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
                            <script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
                            <script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
                            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
                            <style type='text/css'></style>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                if(typeof jQuery == 'undefined')
                                    {
                                        //document.write(unescape("&lt;script type=&#39;text/javascript&#39; src=&quot;https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;"));
                                    }
                            </script>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                var sortingOrder = 'name';
                            </script>
                            <script type='text/javascript'>
                                //<![CDATA[ 

                                var app = angular.module("SearchApp", []);

                                app.controller("SearchCtrl", function($scope,$filter) {

                                            $scope.sortingOrder = sortingOrder;
                                            $scope.reverse = false;
                                            $scope.filteredItems = [];
                                            $scope.groupedItems = [];
                                            $scope.itemsPerPage = 5;
                                            $scope.pagedItems = [];
                                            $scope.currentPage = 0;
                                            $scope.items = [];

                                  $scope.showAll = function() {
                                           $scope.items = [
                                                {"id":"1","name":"name 1","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 1","field4":"field4 1","field5 ":"field5 1"}, 
                                                {"id":"2","name":"name 2","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 2","field4":"field4 2","field5 ":"field5 2"}, 
                                                {"id":"3","name":"name 3","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 3","field4":"field4 3","field5 ":"field5 3"}, 
                                                {"id":"4","name":"name 4","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 4","field4":"field4 4","field5 ":"field5 4"}, 
                                                {"id":"5","name":"name 5","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 5","field4":"field4 5","field5 ":"field5 5"}, 
                                                {"id":"6","name":"name 6","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 6","field4":"field4 6","field5 ":"field5 6"}, 
                                                {"id":"7","name":"name 7","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 7","field4":"field4 7","field5 ":"field5 7"}, 
                                                {"id":"8","name":"name 8","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 8","field4":"field4 8","field5 ":"field5 8"}, 
                                                {"id":"9","name":"name 9","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 9","field4":"field4 9","field5 ":"field5 9"}, 
                                                {"id":"10","name":"name 10","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 10","field4":"field4 10","field5 ":"field5 10"}, 
                                                {"id":"11","name":"name 11","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 11","field4":"field4 11","field5 ":"field5 11"}, 
                                                {"id":"12","name":"name 12","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 12","field4":"field4 12","field5 ":"field5 12"}, 
                                                {"id":"13","name":"name 13","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 13","field4":"field4 13","field5 ":"field5 13"}, 
                                                {"id":"14","name":"name 14","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 14","field4":"field4 14","field5 ":"field5 14"}, 
                                                {"id":"15","name":"name 15","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 15","field4":"field4 15","field5 ":"field5 15"}, 
                                                {"id":"16","name":"name 16","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 16","field4":"field4 16","field5 ":"field5 16"}, 
                                                {"id":"17","name":"name 17","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 17","field4":"field4 17","field5 ":"field5 17"}, 
                                                {"id":"18","name":"name 18","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 18","field4":"field4 18","field5 ":"field5 18"}, 
                                                {"id":"19","name":"name 19","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 19","field4":"field4 19","field5 ":"field5 19"}, 
                                                {"id":"20","name":"name 20","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 20","field4":"field4 20","field5 ":"field5 20"}
                                           ];  
                                           $scope.filteredItems = $scope.items;
                                            $scope.groupToPages();  
                                          $event.preventDefault();

                                           };

                                           var searchMatch = function (haystack, needle) {
                                                if (!needle) {
                                                    return true;
                                                }
                                                return haystack.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
                                            };

                                    // init the filtered items
                                            $scope.search = function () {
                                                $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.items, function (item) {
                                                    for(var attr in item) {
                                                        if (searchMatch(item[attr], $scope.query))
                                                            return true;
                                                    }
                                                    return false;
                                                });
                                                // take care of the sorting order
                                                if ($scope.sortingOrder !== '') {
                                                    $scope.filteredItems = $filter('orderBy')($scope.filteredItems, $scope.sortingOrder, $scope.reverse);
                                                }
                                                $scope.currentPage = 0;
                                                // now group by pages   
                                                 $scope.groupToPages();                                         
                                            };

                                             $scope.groupToPages = function () {
                                                $scope.pagedItems = [];

                                                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.filteredItems.length; i++) {
                                                    if (i % $scope.itemsPerPage === 0) {
                                                        $scope.pagedItems[Math.floor(i / $scope.itemsPerPage)] = [ $scope.filteredItems[i] ];
                                                    } else {
                                                        $scope.pagedItems[Math.floor(i / $scope.itemsPerPage)].push($scope.filteredItems[i]);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            };

                                            $scope.range = function (start, end) {
                                                var ret = [];
                                                if (!end) {
                                                    end = start;
                                                    start = 0;
                                                }
                                                for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
                                                    ret.push(i);
                                                }
                                                return ret;
                                            };

                                              $scope.prevPage = function () {
                                                if ($scope.currentPage > 0) {
                                                    $scope.currentPage--;
                                                }
                                            };

                                            $scope.nextPage = function () {
                                                if ($scope.currentPage < $scope.pagedItems.length - 1) {
                                                    $scope.currentPage++;
                                                }
                                            };

                                            $scope.setPage = function () {
                                                $scope.currentPage = this.n;
                                            };

                                            // change sorting order
                                            $scope.sort_by = function(newSortingOrder) {

                                                if ($scope.sortingOrder == newSortingOrder)
                                                    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;

                                                $scope.sortingOrder = newSortingOrder;

                                                // icon setup
                                                $('th i').each(function(){
                                                    // icon reset
                                                    $(this).removeClass().addClass('icon-sort');
                                                });
                                                if ($scope.reverse)
                                                    $('th.'+newSortingOrder+' i').removeClass().addClass('icon-chevron-up');
                                                else
                                                    $('th.'+newSortingOrder+' i').removeClass().addClass('icon-chevron-down');
                                            };

                                });
                                //]]>
                            </script>
                        </asp:Content>
                        <%-- The markup and script in the following Content element will be placed in the <body>of the page --%>
                            <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
                                <body>
                                    <body ng-app="SearchApp">
                                        <div ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
                                            <div style="float:left">                                                
                                                <div class="input-append">
                                                    <input type="text" ng-model="query" ng-change="search()" class="input-large search-query" placeholder="Search">
                                                    <span class="add-on">
                                                        <i class="icon-search"></i>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <button type="button" ng-click="showAll()">Show all</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div style="float:left;width:80%">
                                                <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
                                                    <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th class="id">
                                                                <a ng-click="sort_by('id')">Id&nbsp;<i class="icon-sort"></i></a>
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th class="name">
                                                                <a ng-click="sort_by('name')">Name&nbsp;<i class="icon-sort"></i></a>
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th class="description">
                                                                <a ng-click="sort_by('description')">Description&nbsp;<i class="icon-sort"></i></a>
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th class="field3">
                                                                <a ng-click="sort_by('field3')">Field 3&nbsp;<i class="icon-sort"></i></a>
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th class="field4">
                                                                <a ng-click="sort_by('field4')">Field 4&nbsp;<i class="icon-sort"></i></a>
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th class="field5">
                                                                <a ng-click="sort_by('field5')">Field 5&nbsp;<i class="icon-sort"></i></a>
                                                            </th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tfoot>
                                                        <td colspan="6">
                                                            <div class="pagination pull-right">
                                                                <ul>
                                                                    <li ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == 0}">
                                                                        <a href ng-click="prevPage()">« Prev</a>
                                                                    </li>
                                                                    <li ng-repeat="n in range(pagedItems.length)" ng-class="{active: n == currentPage}" ng-click="setPage()">
                                                                        <a href ng-bind="n + 1">1</a>
                                                                    </li>
                                                                    <li ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == pagedItems.length - 1}">
                                                                        <a href ng-click="nextPage()">Next »</a>
                                                                    </li>
                                                                </ul>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tfoot>
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr ng-repeat="item in pagedItems[currentPage] | orderBy: 'id'">
                                                            <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                                                            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                                                            <td>{{item.description}}</td>
                                                            <td>{{item.field3}}</td>
                                                            <td>{{item.field4}}</td>
                                                            <td>{{item.field5}}</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </body>
                                </body>
                            </asp:Content>
```